# PrimeNG button for loop text.

Tags: html, angular, primeng

How do you set the label field of a PrimeNG buttons to multiple object fields if you are inside of an ngFor?

Here is my code:

```
    <button pButton type="button" 
            *ngFor="let atrConfig of atrConfigs; let i = index" 
            (click)="selectConfiguration(atrConfig)" label = "">
        Name: {{atrConfig.name}} <br />
    </button>
```

This will create several buttons with the text I am looking for, however, the text "ui-button" always shows up at the end (see image). [image]

Note that I place the text **outside** of the label tag. I've tried placing the text inside the label but the value inside {{ }} does not get printed.

Basically, what's the proper way to use an ngFor with PrimeNG buttons with complex text?

Comment: What do you want to print in the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ui-button" text disappeared when I changed `label = ""` to `label = " "` (I made it a blank space instead of empty quotes).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you do not want to use the `label`, just omit it and then you will see that the text `ui-button` is not printed any longer.

Comment: Didn't work. I posted a solution I found and marked it as the answer.